# Rails 5 ActsAsTaggable Mass Update tags in rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

So I'm trying to update any of my relevant resources with a new tag, based off what the old one is.

Any Post that is tagged with `test`, I want to update it so that all those Posts that are tagged with test will now be tagged with `new-testing-tag` for example.

My other question is, if I have multiple tags associated with a Post, and I just wanted to update one of them, would the process by the same?

for example: Post has tags "javascript" and "premium" -- i just want to change "premium" to free. Is this possible?

tried all of these, in the 
rails console

```
Post.tagged_with("test").update_all(tag: "new-testing-tag")
Post.tagged_with("test").update_all(tags: "test2")
Post.tagged_with("test").update_all(tag_list: "test2")
```

none of them worked though, all of them throw this back: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "tag" of relation "multiple_choice_questions" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE "multiple_choice_questions" SET "tag" = 'test2' WHERE...

This is in my schema.db file

```
  create_table "taggings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "tag_id"
    t.string "taggable_type"
    t.bigint "taggable_id"
    t.string "tagger_type"
    t.bigint "tagger_id"
    t.string "context", limit: 128
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.index ["context"], name: "index_taggings_on_context"
    t.index ["tag_id", "taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context", "tagger_id", "tagger_type"], name: "taggings_idx", unique: true
    t.index ["tag_id"], name: "index_taggings_on_tag_id"
    t.index ["taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context"], name: "index_taggings_on_taggable_id_and_taggable_type_and_context"
    t.index ["taggable_id", "taggable_type", "tagger_id", "context"], name: "taggings_idy"
    t.index ["taggable_id"], name: "index_taggings_on_taggable_id"
    t.index ["taggable_type", "taggable_id"], name: "index_taggings_on_taggable_type_and_taggable_id"
    t.index ["taggable_type"], name: "index_taggings_on_taggable_type"
    t.index ["tagger_id", "tagger_type"], name: "index_taggings_on_tagger_id_and_tagger_type"
    t.index ["tagger_id"], name: "index_taggings_on_tagger_id"
    t.index ["tagger_type", "tagger_id"], name: "index_taggings_on_tagger_type_and_tagger_id"
  end

  create_table "tags", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "taggings_count", default: 0
    t.index ["name"], name: "index_tags_on_name", unique: true
  end
```

Comment: hmm can you check your DB and see is there Tag table and inside Post table just some reference tag field?

Comment: @Nezir I updated my question with the contents of my schema!

Comment: Checking gem documentations I dont see option for update_all so I think you will need to do that manually on tags table. In that case you can generate new migration and write code to find every tag with test and update into something else.

Comment: @Nezir Any idea on how to go about doing that?

Comment: can you check is there 'test' values inside tags table? or any value tag you wish to update, are these in tags table?

Comment: If I do this in the rails console `Post.tagged_with("test")` that works @Nezir

Comment: Yes that would work because tagged_with is a gem method for getting tag, but you should go into rails c   console or open db table with some db ide for sqlite or pgadmin for postgreql db view er.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay,  lets finish this task:

I really couldn't find better solution for updating tag inside this gem ActsAsTaggableOn, but as I suppose before in my comment above we can manage to get this done by using rails migration and updating tags name with plain SQL.

So, I did it like this:
1 - `rails g migration UpdateTags`
    (in terminal I run this command to generate new migration file)
2 - opened generated migration and wrote the code:

```
    class UpdateTags < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
     def change
      execute "UPDATE tags SET name='somenewtag' WHERE LOWER('tags'.'name') LIKE 'rubyonrails.ba' ESCAPE '!';" 
     end
    end
```

3 - save file and run `rails db:migrate`

As you can see in sql command my goal was to update any tags with name value 'rubyonrails.ba'  to new tags name with value 'somenewtag'. You can change this values by your needs. I hope this solution is good enough.

Note: you can write many lines in one migration to update many tags in one migration.

[image]

Comment: getting this error :\
```=======================================
-- execute("UPDATE tags SET name='semester5, pharmacology, blood' WHERE LOWER('tags'.'name') LIKE 'test' ESCAPE '!';")
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 1: ...semester5, pharmacology, blood' WHERE LOWER('tags'.'name') L...
                                                             ^
: UPDATE tags SET name='semester5, pharmacology, blood' WHERE LOWER('tags'.'name') LIKE 'test' ESCAPE '!';```

Comment: look you will need to set every tag on single line try update only one name 'semester5'  and copy paste line below for other

Comment: or try without , between tags like execute("UPDATE tags SET name='semester5 pharmacology blood' WHERE LOWER('tags'.'name') LIKE 'test' ESCAPE '!';")

Comment: ```execute("UPDATE tags SET name='semester5 pharmacology blood' WHERE LOWER('tags'.'name') LIKE 'test' ESCAPE '!';")
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 1: ...='semester5 pharmacology blood' WHERE LOWER('tags'.'name') L...```

Comment: not sure whats happening on your side but it works at my side check screenshot on my answer

Comment: is it because you are using SQLite? I am using PG on development environment

Comment: hmm yes that could be a difference,  sorry I cant use now postgres, but can you check postgresql differences in  writing update query between sqlite and postgres

Comment: in general try remove this ESCAPE '!'  and run again and also you can check 'postgresql update query where like'     just for exact format of query specific to psql

Comment: this is working, but it's adding a double quote to the start and end of my new replacement string. for example, i want `semester5, pharmacology, blood` as the replacement but i am GETTING `"semester5, pharmacology, blood"` any idea?

Comment: https://www.google.ba/search?q=postgresql+escape+double+quote&oq=postgresql+esc&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0l5.16411j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8